# particle.subSelf() Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, particles

I am trying to give velocity and an origin to a particle with threes but i cant add the origin

```
 function getOrigin() {
    return new THREE.Vector3(Weapon.vehicle.position.x, Weapon.vehicle.position.y, Weapon.vehicle.position.z);
}
function start() {
    time = Weapon.time;
    done = false;

    var origin = getOrigin();
    particles = new THREE.Geometry();
    var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
        color: Weapon.explosion.color,
        size: Weapon.explosion.size,
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/particula.png"),
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    });
    for(var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
        // create a particle with random
        // position values, -250 -> 250
        var pX = (Math.random() * Weapon.vehicle.size.x) - (Weapon.vehicle.size.x / 2),
            pY = (Math.random() * Weapon.vehicle.size.y) - (Weapon.vehicle.size.y / 2),
            pZ = (Math.random() * Weapon.vehicle.size.z) - (Weapon.vehicle.size.z / 2),
            particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);

        // create a velocity vector
        particle.velocity = particle.clone();
        particle.addSelf(origin);

        // add it to the geometry
        particles.vertices.push(particle);
    }

    // create the particle system
    particleSystem = new THREE.ParticleSystem(particles, pMaterial);
    particleSystem.sortParticles = true;
    scene.add(particleSystem);
}
```

particle.addSelf(origin); this line gives me an undefined function it was working fine with an older version of threes but i wanted to upgrade from r52 to r67 and i am finding lots of issues please if you have an idea any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the migration notes here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration
and the release notes here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases